# Mysql foreign key and delete record

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have created two tables and they have a simple fk relationship. The tables are like below:

```
table_1
   field_1 (primary key)

table_3
   field_1 (fk on table_1)
   field_2 (fk on table_2)
```

and then I have created the FK with the line below:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_2` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (field_1`) REFERENCES `table_1` (`field_1`);
```

What I expect is that, if I try to delete a record in my table_1 where field_1 = x and another record with the same x value is present in table_2 as field_1, I should get an error.
Actually, I don't get any error and the record is removed from table_1 leaving an orphan child record in table_2.
I don't use the delete cascade because I want avoid this.

Why I don't get any error?

Comment: You need to add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause to your constraint.

Comment: delete cascade would delete the child. the op wants an error to raise.

Comment: It should throw an error, the default behavior is RESTRICT. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Which engine, InnoDb or MyIsam ? Foreign keys in MySql are implemented only for InnoDb, for MyIsam foreign key constraints are simply ignored.

Comment: @kordirko: damn you are right! I always forget about it and the hosting I took gives me MyIslam as engine and no way to switch to InnoDb :(